# Detecting non static objects while a robot is moving

Tags: ros, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a turtlebot 2.0 (groovy) with a laser rangefinder (Hokuyo urg04lx) and a kinect. The robot performs navigation and mapping very well.
Now I'd like it to recognize moving objects, especially people, while moving as well. So I made some considerations I'd like to share with you, any feedback woud be appreciated :

- Using "Detecting people on a ground plane with RGB-D data" from pcl. But this might be overkill.
- Using "Canonical Scan Matcher" **outliers** somehow. Then stop the robot and launch NITE user tracker to remove any doubt. A lot more efficient I guess, but I don't know how to publish outliers.
- Same kind of approach as above but with a own implementation. Using for instance obstacles in the local map and comparing prediction and observation just like this paper: "Dynamic object detection using Laser data and transforming the points to lines". But I'm sure there is an easier solution than reinventing the wheel.

Which approach should I consider first ? Do you see anything else even easier than those suggestions ?

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62171/detecting-non-static-objects-while-a-robot-is-moving/) by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2013-05-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) on 2013-06-06**:
Hi there, any advice ?

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-17**:
@Rouno im trying to accomplish the same, navigate with people moving.  To detect people i used the code in pcl17 package and it works well.  Any question regarding this im happy to reply, also have you been able to navigate with moving objects?

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-10-21**:
Discussions are easier in Forums, try this one: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/ros-sig-navigation maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ctguell,
I guess you're using people detector on ground plane from pcl aren't you ? We also gave it a try but as our robot camera shoots on below, the algorithm didn't work very well. For now we're using a laser based people detection but I'm sure that taking care of ICP outliers would definitely be the best option.

---

Originally posted by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) with karma: 68 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-18**:
@Rouno have you been able to navigate with moving objects? Thanks